# Tool to capitalize all methods/properties/fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any tool for **C#** (maybe some add-in for **Visual Studio**) that can capitalize all methods/properties/fields in project?

**EDIT1:** Note, ReSharper hasn't such possibility

**EDIT2:** I mean capitalize just First Letters!

**EDIT3:**  ReSharper can do it manually, i.e. user should traverse ALL entities and fix it choosing proper option from context menu. I talk about button that do that automatically for ALL selected code

Comment: ReSharper hasn't such possibility

Comment: DO YOU REALLY WANNA MAKE THEM IN CAPS ?

Comment: Why would you want to capitalize fields?

Comment: @MichaelZ, yes, it does!

Comment: @JonSkeet See mine EDIT2

Comment: @MichaelZ: That doesn't answer the question - other than *public* fields, (which should usually just be constants) you'd normally make fields `camelCased`.

Comment: My wild guess is that he tries to port Java code...

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, forget about fields

Comment: @Shai ReSharper can do it manually, i.e. user should traverse ALL entities and fix it choosing proper option from context menu. I talk about button that do that automatically for ALL selected code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it: how did the tool will knows where the word boundaries in set of characters which is written by user as identifier? Seams like it possible to create some capitalizer tool based on dictionary. But any way you'll must to check its results and fix issues.

Comment: Well Visual Studio sure knows the properties that aren't capitalized aren't following standards. It highlights them and will even refactor them for you, but you have to do them one at a time. It would be nice if the refactor worked on several things at once.